# Por qué no puedo usar vuejs en mi proyecto?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Le he dado muchas vueltas al asunto y no hayo cual es el problema les comento, estoy usando laravel 8. vuejs "vue": "^2.6.12".

este es mi webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js(['resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'resources/js/vue.js',
'resources/js/axios.js',
'resources/js/toastr.js',
'resources/js/app.js',
'resources/js/app2.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

(no estoy manejando css desde aqui)

```
<body>

<div id="app">
      @yield('content')
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-DZqqY3PiOvTP9HkjIWgjO6ouCbq+dxqWoJZ/Q+zPYNHmlnI2dQnbJ5bxAHpAMw+LXRm4D72EIRXzvcHQtE8/VQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

mi resource/js/app2.js:

```
var url = '/';
var urlClientes = url + 'vistaclientes';
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#creditos',
    data: {
      clientes: [],
      nombre: '',
    },
    methods:{
      getClientes: function (){
        axios.get(urlClientes).then(response => {
          this.clientes = response.data
        });
      }
    }
});
```

mi index.blade.php:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="getClientes" >Listar</button>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in clientes">
            @{{item.nombre}}
          </li>
        </ul>
```

mi vistaclientes:

```
[{"id":1,"nombre":"Jose Perez"},{"id":2,"nombre":"Juan Lopez"}]
```

estoy tratando de listar los clientes pero no me aparece nada al darle click en el boton listar, pero no sé por que?

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste correr npm install en tu proyecto?

Comment: ya esta instalado, al darle npm run dev me compila todo

Comment: Donde está la etiqueta con id `creditos`?

Comment: esta en view->Creditos->index.blade.php